# HTML-tags in tooltip

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to show a tooltip in Twitter Bootstrap that uses html tags in it to give it some mark-up?

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
<a class="my-tooltip" rel="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="CPR + O<sub>2</sub>.">First-Aid</a>
```

But it will just show `CPR + 0<sub>2</sub>` in the tooltip when I hover over it.

Can't it be done, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried searching for this question but didn't find it. But yes it can be seen as a duplicate. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the attribute `data-html="true"` to your link

Comment: This fixed it, thanks alot, will accept the answer when Stackoverflow will allow me to.